# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')'

Tags: php

I am getting error on my site
 Parse error: syntax error,
unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' in /home/****/public_html/config.php on line 111

My PHP code in FROM line 107 TO 112 is:

```
 //PayPal Settings
$config [ 'paypal' ] = array(
'url' => ' https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr ' , //url na koeto da prashta formata
'business' => 'http://startmarketplace.com/themeforestclone-demo/, / Your PayPal ID or an email address
' currency ' => ' USD ' //valuta v koqto e cenata EUR, USD etc.
);
```

Start line is 107. Last line is line 112.

Line on which I am getting error is (111) is:
' currency ' => ' USD ' //valuta v koqto e cenata EUR, USD etc

Plz help.. Thanks :)

Comment: I've put this in a code block for you. The highlighting should help you spot the error.

Answer (score 8):

This code should work:

```
<?php
//PayPal Settings
$config [ 'paypal' ] = array(
    'url'       => ' https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr ' , //url na koeto da prashta formata
    'business'  => 'http://startmarketplace.com/themeforestclone-demo/', // Your PayPal ID or an email address
    'currency'  => ' USD ' //valuta v koqto e cenata EUR, USD etc.
);
?>
```

You simply forgot to add a quote ( ' ) to the "business" value in the $config array.

Comment: You're right. I'll update. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 //PayPal Settings
$config['paypal'] = array(
  'url' => 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', 
  'business' => 'http://startmarketplace.com/themeforestclone-demo/', 
  'currency' => 'USD',
);
```

Comment: Did'nt worked :/ Dont know why..

Comment: Because there is a syntax error in his code.. Use mine instead.